# Assigning JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS results to a VARCHAR array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-json

When trying to assign results of a [JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) call to a [VARCHAR array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html) (for later use in `SELECT ... WHERE IN (UNNEST(...))` statements), the following stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(
        IN in_sids jsonb,
        OUT out_uid integer)
        RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
        sids varchar[];
        uids integer[];
BEGIN
        sids := (SELECT x->>'sid' FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_sids) x);
        -- uids := (SELECT uid FROM social WHERE sid IN (UNNEST(sids)));

        RAISE NOTICE 'sids = %', sids;
        RAISE NOTICE 'uids = %', uids;

        SELECT 1;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

unfortunately prints the error:

```
# select test1('[{"sid":"aaa"},{"sid":"bbb"}]'::jsonb);

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (SELECT x->>'sid' FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_sids) x)"
PL/pgSQL function test1(jsonb) line 6 at assignment
```

So I have tried to fix the assignment by using [ARRAY_AGG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) -

```
sids := SELECT ARRAY_AGG(SELECT x->>'sid' FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_sids) x);
```

but get the syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 10:         sids := SELECT ARRAY_AGG(SELECT x->>'sid' FROM JSONB...
                         ^
```

How to store `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS` results to an array please?

**UPDATE:**

I have followed Nick's advise (thank you), but now stuck at the next step:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(
        IN in_sids jsonb,
        OUT out_uid integer)
        RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
        sids varchar[];
        uids integer[];
BEGIN
        sids := (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x->>'sid') FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_sids) x);
        uids := (SELECT uid FROM social WHERE sid IN (UNNEST(sids)));

        SELECT 1;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

when trying to use the array in a `SELECT ... WHERE IN ...` statement:

```
# select test1('[{"sid":"aaa"},{"sid":"bbb"}]'::jsonb);
ERROR:  argument of IN must not return a set
LINE 1: SELECT (SELECT uid FROM social WHERE sid IN (UNNEST(si...
                                              ^
QUERY:  SELECT (SELECT uid FROM social WHERE sid IN (UNNEST(sids)))
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test1(jsonb) line 7 at assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close...

```
sids := (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x->>'sid') FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_sids) x);
```

In order to use the [`expression IN (subquery)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) construct, you need to write a self-contained `SELECT` statement:

```
uids := (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(uid) FROM social WHERE sid IN (SELECT UNNEST(sids)));
```

Alternatively, you can check if a value is in an array using [`ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19765):

```
uids := (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(uid) FROM social WHERE sid = ANY(sids));
```

If you're not using the `sids` array for some later calculation, you can combine these into one query:

```
uids := (
  SELECT array_agg(uid)
  FROM social
  JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_sids) x ON
    sid = x->>'sid'
);
```

Comment: Actually I use `sids` too, but thank you. Wouldn't `ANY` be slower than `UNNEST`?

Comment: If the `sid` column is indexed, and relatively selective, then `ANY` will generally be faster. The `UNNEST` version has a lot more flexibility in terms of query plans, and tends to come out on top in cases where indexing doesn't help. If in doubt, just compare the `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` output between the two queries.